# How to access 'Your Music' section?

Tags: javascript, spotify

With API 1.x, I can't find a way to access Data in the new 'Your music' section.
There is property Library.tracks and Library.albums, but it is marked as 'This property is currently unsupported and should not be used'.

Answer (score 0):

'Your Music' is not supported by the Apps API. I'd really recommend keeping an eye out for news regarding our Web API on our [Developer site](http://developer.spotify.com/) though.